# Rectangle detection in image using Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, shapes, detection

I have an image with many shapes and I need to write some Matlab code which remove all the shapes except the rectangle.. Does it availabe to do it using **only** with strel,imclose and bwareaopen? if you think yes i will be very happy to hear your opinion/idea.

The image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWZ7I.png

Comment: Pleas don't post twice the same question. You might improve the original in order to get answers. thanks!

Comment: I have no what to improve no one help here